# HTML - text next to a div without giving it a fixed width

Tags: html, css

I've got multiple div elements nested in a div. What I want is for the `#title-text` div to be next to the image - in this case using a float.

The problem is that the text in the div spaces out the div when it has no more room in width as you can see in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogkj1ahr/).

I want to use floats because there will be multiple tiles using the same classes, and those tiles have different sizes and images etc. Also I don't want to have the `#title-text` to have a fixed width because of multiple tiles using it and thus having different widths.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="tile-wrapper">
    <div id="category-text">
        <p class="category-content">Smartphones / software</p>
    </div>                        
        <div id="tile-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/wp10.jpg" class="tile-image" name="title" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="title-text">
            <a href="#" class="title-text">Placeholder Text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text</a>
        </div>
    <div id="date-time-text">
        <p class="date-time">3 minutes ago.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Remove #title-wrapper height, hope its what you looking.

Comment: That would work if I didn't want the text in this case to be next to the image instead of beneath it. @Sun_Sparxz

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first I added display inline to your classes like this

```
.tile-image {
margin: 0 auto;
display:inline;
}

.title-text {
margin: 0 5px 5px 0px;
font-weight: 300;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 22px;
color: black;
display:inline;
}
```

then I put a width and alignment on #title-text

```
#title-text {
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
text-align:left;
width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question with Jquery. Here's the solution if anyone wonders.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imageWidth = $('#tile-image').width();
    var titleTextWidth = $('#title-text').width();

    $('#title-text').width(imageWidth);
    $('#tile-wrapper').width(imageWidth * 2 + 30); // +30 for margins. 

});
```